# Express.js: Is this a RESTful interface?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am pretty new to node and express.js and I'm new to the concept of REST applications as well. I want to code a typical CRUD app, some sort of diary. Hence, I have a collection of entries, can view a single entry and can add, edit and delete an entry. 
I'm not quite getting yet, how URi's have to be set up to represent a REST conform API. I would create something like this in my app.js:

```
// GET REQUEST ROUTING
app.get('/', diary_router.home);
app.get('/entries/', diary_router.listEntries);
app.get('/entries/:id', diary_router.getSingleEntry);

// POST REQUEST ROUTING
app.post('/entries/', diary_router.addEntry);

// PUT REQUEST ROUTING
app.put('/entries/', diary_router.updateEntry);

// DELETE REQUEST ROUTING
app.delete('/entries/', diary_router.deleteEntry);
```

Could that be called a REST conform interface? Should I rather add the respective action in the routes, such as this and does the item-ID need to be shown in the URL for PUT and DELETE actions, too?:

```
// GET REQUEST ROUTING
app.get('/', diary_router.home);
app.get('/entries/', diary_router.listEntries);
app.get('/entries/show/:id', diary_router.getSingleEntry);

// POST REQUEST ROUTING
app.post('/entries/add/', diary_router.addEntry);

// PUT REQUEST ROUTING
app.put('/entries/update/:id', diary_router.updateEntry);

// DELETE REQUEST ROUTING
app.delete('/entries/delete/:id', diary_router.deleteEntry);
```

What would be best practice here? Any help is much appreciated.
B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the loose definition of REST that we seem to have converged on in web-land, the first option seems to fit best.

**Edit:** and yes, you should specify the ID in the `PUT` and `DELETE` routes.

HTTP is a really cool protocol for applying verbs (request methods) to nouns (URLs). In that spirit, it's probably best to use the request method to differentiate what you want to do to the resource that you're requesting.

**Note:** you can use the [methodOverride](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/methodOverride.html) middleware in express if you're worried about browsers not being able to use arbitrary HTTP methods.

*The way the methodOverride middleware works is that you use an `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` or similar to specify the method, despite it just being a regular `POST` request, and the methodOverride middleware will set the `method` property on the request that you get in your express application. This way, you can signal the intended request method without the client actually having to support that method.*

Comment: Hi deoxxa,
Thanks for your answer. As far as I've seen, methodOverride seems to be set by default in express. 
Next question: How can I create a PUT request? Can I use it as a `<form method="PUT">` attribute to a form element?

Comment: It depends on the browser - I'm not sure which ones support arbitrary HTTP methods like that. The way the methodOverride middleware works is that you use an `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` or similar to specify the method, despite it just being a regular `POST` request, and the methodOverride middleware will set the `method` property on the request that you get in your express application.

Comment: This detailed comment should probably be an amendment to your original answer! +1 otherwise, great answer. Would read again! A++